# Jquery recursive Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, sharepoint

Can anyone figure out how to convert this to using promises. I have tried several things bit it does not seem to be working. I Inherited this code from someone it runs on a SharePoint page. Part of the problem is the Async:false setup. And When I tried to set it to true all sorts things broke on the ribbon tool bar, unfortunately the I dont have access to the ribbon code.

```
function findChildren(item, ctxT) {
    item.children = [];
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: String.format("{0}/_api/web/lists(guid'{1}')/items?$filter=TrackingUnderNumber eq '{2}'", ctxT.HttpRoot, SP.Guid._normalizeGuidString$p(ctxT.listName), item.TrackingNumber),
        async: false,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            data.d.results.forEach(function (dItem) {
                dItem.parent = item;
                item.children.push(dItem);
                findChildren(dItem, ctxT);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I think part of the reason he chose to go with Async false is he wanted to wait until the entire tree was loaded before enabling buttons and function on ribbon. But there has to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without seeing the rest of the code, but this might work:

```
function getAllChildren(item, ctxT) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const getItemsChildren = () => {
            item.children = [];
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: String.format("{0}/_api/web/lists(guid'{1}')/items?$filter=TrackingUnderNumber eq '{2}'", ctxT.HttpRoot, SP.Guid._normalizeGuidString$p(ctxT.listName), item.TrackingNumber),
                async: false,
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d.results.length > 0){
                        data.d.results.forEach(function (dItem) {
                            dItem.parent = item;
                            item.children.push(dItem);
                            getItemsChildren(dItem, ctxT);
                        });
                    } else {
                        resolve(); 
                    }

                },
                error: (err) => { reject(err); } 
            });
        }; 
        getItemsChildren(); 
    });
}

// then you can do 
getAllChildren(item, ctxt).then(() => { /* do something now */ });

// or inside an async function 
(async () => {
    await getAllChildren(item, ctxt); 
    // do something now
})
```

To make your own Promise you do this:

1. Define your function
2. IMMEDIATELY return a `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...});`
3. Inside that promise, do w/e you need to do (make API calls, etc);
4. When you want the promise to end, simply call 'resolve();`or`reject()`;
5. Data passed to `resolve` and `reject` will be the data you get in `.then`

So if I call `resolve('Promises rock!')` and then I do this `.then((data) => { console.log(data); })`, then I'll expect to see "Promises rock!" as my console log.

Good luck!